# Bulletins and Character numbering in PDF using iTextSharp c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, pdf-generation, itext

My question is How to insert a Ordered List `<ol>...</ol>` tag in a PDF while converting html to PDF?

So far, my code is

```
List<IElement> htmlarraylist = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(HTMLString), null); 
    foreach (iTextSharp.text.IElement elm in htmlarraylist) 
    { 
        for (int c = 0; c < elm.Chunks.Count; c++) 
        { 
            elm.Chunks[c].Font = NheaderFont; 
        } 
        document.Add(elm); 
    }
```

And my sample HTML String will be

```
<ol style="list-style-type:lower-alpha">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
<li>four</li> </ol>
```

And My expected outcome was

> a.one
>   b.two
>   c.three
>   d.four

But the result (in PDF file) was

> one
>   two
>   three
>   four

Please help me on the above.

Comment: You are using `HTMLWorker`. That class has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker. `HTMLWorker` is no longer supported, so please don't expect an answer. Maybe you're using an old iTextSharp version. In that case, please upgrade, use XML Worker and post a new question if the problem persists.

Comment: Hi @BrunoLowagie.. If HTMLWorker is abandoned, then, is there any other way for my problem . FYI., I am using 5.5.0.0 version of itextsharp.

Comment: Use XML Worker and post a new question if the problem persists. Define the font in the HTML. Don't complicate things by first parsing the HTML and then trying to change the font. There are too many ways you can make errors using that approach.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, Thank you... It works like a charm. Is there a way to override the parsed font by the XML worker?

Comment: You can introduce a `FontProvider` to XML Worker. This is an interface you can implement to force using specific fonts.